# DynamoDB query using search key conditions throwing an odd exception (using PHP)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm querying a DynamoDB table using the method described [here in the AWS PHP developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPQuerying.html).

The array that I pass to the Dynamo connection looks like the following:

```
Array(
    [ConsistentRead] => false
    [TableName] => bbq_lol_test
    [KeyConditions] => Array(
            [stinky_cheese] => Array(
                    [ComparisonOperator] => EQ
                    [AttributeValueList] => Array(
                            [S] => camembert)

                )
        )
)
```

As you can see, it's in the exact format that the example uses, with the exception of the `Type` enum (which is just a string).

When executing `$connection->query` with the above array as an argument, I get the following exception:

```
Guzzle\Service\Exception\ValidationException: 
Validation errors: [KeyConditions][stinky_cheese][AttributeValueList][S][AttributeValue] must be of type object
```

Which is odd, because the array in the stack trace appears to be fine:

```
Aws/Common/Client/AbstractClient.php(103): Guzzle\Service\Client->__call("Query", array(array("ConsistentRead" => false, "TableName" => "bbq_lol_test", "KeyConditions" => array("stinky_cheese" => array("ComparisonOperator" => "EQ", "AttributeValueList" => array("S" => "camembert"))))))
```

I *DO* have an index on the `stinky_cheese` field (since I'm using query). I'm probably doing something daft, but I can't seem to figure it out now. Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There were two problems.

First, `AttributeValueList` should be an array of arrays, not a single array, going from this:

```
[AttributeValueList] => Array([S] => camembert)
```

To this:

```
[AttributeValueList] => Array(Array([S] => camembert))
```

Since it's possible to add more stuff in there, like so:

```
[AttributeValueList] => Array(Array([S] => camembert), Array([S] => bleu))
```

The second problem was that I always have to query using the *primary hash key*, which I was not doing.

Comment: I was halfway through answering this. I'm glad you found the problem.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyLindblom ... it certainly took me a while to figure out. Unfortunately the error output wasn't too helpful.

Comment: It's a validation error from Guzzle. I'll talk to the Guzzle maintainer and see what he thinks about it, and then see if there is anything additional the SDK might do as well.